# how to scale down Cocos2D image repeatedly

Tags: iphone, ios, image-processing, cocos2d-iphone

I'm repeatedly shrinking an image (and then render it to a new full sized image) by a small amount, and the result is that a stripe down the middle is not being shrunk.  I'm assuming this has to do with the resize method cocos2d uses. If I increase the amount I scale down the image by the resize is too fast, and if I decrease the shrink size the bar down the middle gets even bigger! the following code is called 60 times a second.  the picture below shows the result! So.. any suggestions on how to get rid of the bar?

```
 [mySprite setScaleX:rtt.scaleX - .05];
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't sure quite what you meant, but did you mean you're calling this line 60 times a second?

```
 [mySprite setScaleX:rtt.scaleX - .05];
```

If so then your sprite's scale will become negative in a third of a second...

Comment: I render the scaled down image to a new full sized image, and the next scale down operation is applied to the full sized image.  the resulting effect is anything drawn to the screen gets "sucked" into the middle of the screen.

Comment: Have you fixed it?  Interested

Comment: No, I didn't fix it, but I this is just one effect out of about 20 I randomly apply to my image, so I just replaced it with an even better wave effect I found in the cocos2d demo program

Comment: That's a lot of effects. I like it.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you manipulate an image, you lose information.

A better approach would be to always resize from the original, and just change the resize amount each time, rather than continually resizing the result of the last resize operation.

Comment: I should have been more clear in my description, I'm rendering the shrunken image to a new full sized image with each cycle, and the next cycle shrinks that new full sized image.  so I'm ok with losing image data, infact i want to lose it all over time, as im drawing new data on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to cocos2d engine, so hope this helps.  If your shrinking an image, I would suggest using CCScaleBy.  You can try something like this...

> CCScaleBy *yourSprite = [CCScaleBy actionWithDuration: .01 scaleX: .95 scaleY: 1.0f];

This will scale your sprite down by 5% each time its called. Then you can have it replaced by the new image when it reaches what you would consider its smallest pixel point. The duration may need to be played with, but thought this would help.